# Device Tree Bad Data (for PocketBeagle)

Tags: beagleboneblack, device-tree

I am trying to create a device tree overlay for the [PocketBeagle](https://github.com/beagleboard/pocketbeagle/wiki/System-Reference-Manual) to interface to the [MCP3204](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21298c.pdf) ADC. I am trying to use the driver that exists already in the Linux kernel. My device tree source is the following:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "ti,am335x-pocketbeagle";
    part-number = "mm-cape";
    version = "00A0";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
        __overlay__ {
            mm_chipselect: MM_CHIP_SELECT_PIN {
                pinctrl-single,pin = <0xe8 0xf>;
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@1 {
        target = <&ocp>;
        __overlay__ {
            mm_chipselect_helper: helper {
                compatible = "bone-pinmux-helper";
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&mm_chipselect>;
                status = "okay";
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@2 {
        target = <&spi0>;
        __overlay__ {
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            cs-gpios = <&gpio2 24 0>, <0>, <0>, <0>;

            mcp320x: mcp320x@0 {
                compatible = "microchip,mcp3208";
                reg = <0>;
                spi-max-frequency = <1000000>;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

When I load my device tree overlay I get the following output from `dmesg`:

```
[    2.157460] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: bad data for mux MM_CHIP_SELECT_PIN
[    2.164916] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: no pins entries for MM_CHIP_SELECT_PIN
[    2.172687] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: bad data for mux MM_CHIP_SELECT_PIN
[    2.180072] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: no pins entries for MM_CHIP_SELECT_PIN
[    2.187700] bone-pinmux-helper ocp:helper: Failed to get pinctrl
[    2.193762] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[    2.193783] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1 at drivers/base/devres.c:888 devm_kfree+0x4c/0x50()
[    2.193791] Modules linked in:
[    2.193810] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.4.91-ti-r133 #1
[    2.193818] Hardware name: Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree)
[    2.193862] [<c001bed0>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0015978>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[    2.193885] [<c0015978>] (show_stack) from [<c05c1674>] (dump_stack+0x8c/0xa0)
[    2.193905] [<c05c1674>] (dump_stack) from [<c004435c>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x94/0xc4)
[    2.193919] [<c004435c>] (warn_slowpath_common) from [<c0044490>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x2c/0x34)
[    2.193932] [<c0044490>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<c0718418>] (devm_kfree+0x4c/0x50)
[    2.193951] [<c0718418>] (devm_kfree) from [<c073bea8>] (bone_pinmux_helper_probe+0x1c4/0x260)
[    2.193966] [<c073bea8>] (bone_pinmux_helper_probe) from [<c0716368>] (platform_drv_probe+0x60/0xc0)
[    2.193990] [<c0716368>] (platform_drv_probe) from [<c0713fcc>] (driver_probe_device+0x234/0x470)
[    2.194005] [<c0713fcc>] (driver_probe_device) from [<c07142a4>] (__driver_attach+0x9c/0xa0)
[    2.194020] [<c07142a4>] (__driver_attach) from [<c0711a80>] (bus_for_each_dev+0x8c/0xd0)
[    2.194035] [<c0711a80>] (bus_for_each_dev) from [<c0713728>] (driver_attach+0x2c/0x30)
[    2.194049] [<c0713728>] (driver_attach) from [<c0713200>] (bus_add_driver+0x1b8/0x278)
[    2.194062] [<c0713200>] (bus_add_driver) from [<c0714d94>] (driver_register+0x88/0x104)
[    2.194075] [<c0714d94>] (driver_register) from [<c0716274>] (__platform_driver_register+0x50/0x58)
[    2.194094] [<c0716274>] (__platform_driver_register) from [<c0f96218>] (bone_pinmux_helper_driver_init+0x1c/0x20)
[    2.194113] [<c0f96218>] (bone_pinmux_helper_driver_init) from [<c00098e4>] (do_one_initcall+0xd8/0x228)
[    2.194133] [<c00098e4>] (do_one_initcall) from [<c0f4c000>] (kernel_init_freeable+0x1ec/0x288)
[    2.194152] [<c0f4c000>] (kernel_init_freeable) from [<c0aa4314>] (kernel_init+0x1c/0xf8)
[    2.194172] [<c0aa4314>] (kernel_init) from [<c0010e00>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x34)
[    2.194217] ---[ end trace 20e7a3ce9aa45d9c ]---
[    2.194310] bone-pinmux-helper: probe of ocp:helper failed with error -22
[    2.222490] spi spi1.0: failed to request gpio
[    2.227072] omap2_mcspi 48030000.spi: can't setup spi1.0, status -16
[    2.233483] spi_master spi1: spi_device register error /ocp/spi@48030000/mcp320x@0
[    2.241309] spi_master spi1: Failed to create SPI device for /ocp/spi@48030000/mcp320x@0
```

I can't seem to find what the source of the error could be. I have confirmed using multiple other examples that the structure of the file should be correct, and that the pin offset and mux value are correct. What could be causing this error?